# Inspiration for Warren Worthington in the "X-Men"?

Tags: inspiration, comics, stan-lee, jack-kirby

When Stan Lee and Jack Kirby created the X-Men, what was the inspiration and concept behind the superhero character [Warren Worthington III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warren_Worthington_III)? Why did they choose the idea of him being a wealthy billionaire playboy as well as his physical appearance?

Comment: It makes him a better rival for Scott for Jean's affections, being rich and fun-loving.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't believe that it was ever confirmed by the writers, I have often seen people claiming that Edmond Hamilton's "[He That Hath Wings](https://archive.org/details/wt_1938_07/page/n71/mode/2up?view=theater)" was probably the basis of the character. Along with being a winged humanoid, there's the hollow bones and the altered blood to support flying.